# Jquery and Dialog Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having one hell of a time trying to get this to work, no javascript errors what so ever. Its just going right to the action. Here is the javascript I am using

> $(function(){
>
> ```
>       $("form[name=form1]").submit(function(){
>           return $("#dialog").dialog({
>               autoOpen:false,
>               bgiframe: true,
>               resizable: false,
>               //height:auto,
>               width:500,
>               modal: true,
>               overlay: {
>                   backgroundColor: '#000',
>                   opacity: 0.5
>               },
>               buttons: {
>                   'I Agree': function() {
>                       $(this).dialog('close');
>                       return true;
>                   },
>                   'I Do Not Agree': function() {
>                       $(this).dialog('close');
>                       return false;
>                   }
>               }
>           });     
>     });
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put the submit button outside of the `<form></form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dialog method you are calling returns immediately and the buttons functions are called asynchronously, when the buttons are clicked. I suggest that you attach a simple click event to your submit button. The click event will open the dialog and the 'I agree' function will submit the form.

Comment: I added a click function to it, http://pastie.org/private/5z0cqb5zf7o2jqmjgyfjea and made the button have an id of #button, nothing happens at all.

Comment: If #button is a submit button, add a 'return false;' to the end of the click handler to avoid submission. Other than that, I see no problem with your code. You may want to try Firebug to see what is happening.